# Is there a JavaScript-based Python?

Tags: javascript, python, webassembly

I have a lot of JavaScript I need to write. I can do that, but I have some Python already which does something similar. I'd much prefer to adapt that and have it run within the browser.

There's the C-based reference implementation, and there's Jython in Java. Is there a JavaScript implementation along the same lines?

I have looked, but it may be that my google-fu has failed me. And it seems like something that *ought* to exist. Have I missed it?

Comment: Something like https://realpython.com/brython-python-in-browser/  ?

Comment: This question doesn't deserve to be closed IMHO. The OP isn't looking for recommendations or opinions on libraries, but is more asking if browsers can run Python - which is a pretty specific question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for something like`WebAssembly`, used for running non JavaScript code in the browser. `pyodide` would be a good starting point

- https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide
- https://medium.com/swlh/python-in-web-easy-5f7de3813055